# Different project properties in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I am trying to run 2 different projects from Github in eclipse one is 
[Jhotdraw](https://github.com/wumpz/jhotdraw) and other is  [Retrofit](https://github.com/refdiff-data/retrofit). My aim is to compute some metric values using a plugin when I check the project properties both show differntly [image: retrofit properties][image: Jhotdraw properties]. Can anybody tell me why is that? and how to add the missing properties?

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to *jhotdraw7*, *retrofit* is not shared as an Eclipse project: either it has not been created with Eclipse or the files `.project` and `.classpath` has been excluded from sharing.

In the `.project` file the project natures are defined. In *jhotdraw7*, the line

[`<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>`](https://github.com/wumpz/jhotdraw/blob/develop/jhotdraw7/.project#L15)

tells Eclipse that it is a Java project. Properties like *Java Build Path* are only shown for Java projects.

Projects that are not shared as Eclipse projects can be automatically detected (based on its content, e. g. a `pom.xml` files or `*.java` files) and configured via [Eclipse Smart Import](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import):

- ***File > Open Projects from File System...***
- In the ***Git Repositories*** view, right click the ***Working Tree*** node and choose ***Import Projects...***

In your case:

1. **Delete the project *retrofit*** without the option *Delete the project contents on disc*
2. In the ***retrofit* delete the file `.project`** and undo all changes you have made in the meantime (e. g. in the ***Git Repositories*** view, by right-clicking the *retrofit* repository root node, selecting *Reset...* and in the *Reset* dialog choosing *Hard*)
3. In the ***Git Repositories*** view, right click the ***Working Tree*** node and choose ***Import Projects...***

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, the properties available in the  project properties menu are specific to the project type.
The project type is stored in project metadata.

Your `Jhotdraw` project is configured as a Java project.
So multiple properties related to are present.

While  your `Retrofit` project is not configured as a Java project. 
So Java `properties` doesn't appear.
To make Java `properties` visible, you have to configure the project as a Java project.
You have many ways to do that : maven, ant, gradle, default Java project..
I see that the retrofit project on GIT contains a pom.xml.
So import the project as an existing Maven project and it should be fine :

> File Menu -> Import -> Existing Maven Project.

And then select the local directory where you have checked-out Retrofit.

Comment: both are java project so why properties are different?

Comment: Import the project with Maven as it is a Maven Project.

Comment: I imported them using Git (project from git)

Comment: It should not be a problem.  You can remove the project from the Eclipse view (delete the project without checking the box "delete on disk") and then import the Maven project from your local directory where the project GIT was checked out.